# Git merge conflict in file I've never modified

Tags: android, git, android-source, git-merge, git-rebase

I've been working on Android source code for the past few weeks.

On the platform/build repository, I checked out the android-4.0.4_r2.1 tag. This became my 'ics' branch. Now, when either merging or rebasing against the android-4.1.1_r1 tag, I get a merge conflict in a file I've never edited.

These are the repos (and tags) in question:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-4.0.4_r2.1

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/android-4.1.1_r1

This is the branch forked from the first tag, that I am trying to merge the latter tag into:

https://github.com/slimdroid/platform_build/commits/ics

I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this. I am not a total beginner with git, but I don't see how I cannot merge without conflicts this tag when there should be a common base.

For information, my conflict is in core/build_id.mk on the line that specifics the BUILD_ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not advanced in git, so I may be totally wrong here. But I understand your assumption is that the commit pointed by the first tag is an ancestor of the other tag. Only in such a case, you can guarantee that there will be no merge conflicts between them.

You can test this assumption by doing a [`git merge-base first-tag second-tag`](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1%20git-merge-base).

Comment: While this doesn't necessarily answer my question, it would've led me to the right answer had a paid a little bit more attention and knew a tiny bit more about git :) Accepted.

Comment: Thanks. But I feel your answer containing Jean-Baptiste's comment should be marked as accepted, although I too suspected the reason could be because ICS branch got detached ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will copy here Jean-Baptiste's answer, a person who does AOSP work for Google:

> You're not doing anything wrong.
>
> What you're seeing is an artifact of Google's internal development
>   process.
>
> At some point, ICS got detached from the main merge flow within
>   Google, while we were preparing the first release of Jelly Bean. There
>   was still a little bit of ICS activity left, though, which at the git
>   level didn't get merged into Jelly Bean. That's what you're seeing
>   here: there are a few changes in the latest versions of ICS that are
>   not in Jelly Bean, and attempting to rebase the latest ICS on onto
>   Jelly Bean makes those stand out.
>
> Check "repo forall platform/build -c git log
>   android-4.1.1_r1..android-4.0.4_r2.1" - that'll spot that commit
>   that's been surprising you.
>
> JBQ